# Живой поиск System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, фильтр

Добрый день/вечер, столкнулся с задачей сделать контекстный поиск в Windows.Controls.ComboBox. Поиск производится по любому вхождению.
Например имеем: Вася, Федя, Вика
Набираем "в", получаем: Вася, Вика; "ва" остается Вася; "дя" - Федя.
Надеюсь смысл понятен.
Доработал класс ComboBox:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using ProgrammingWeapons;

namespace Telemetria.UI
{
    public class ComboBoxFinder : ComboBox
    {
        private bool _isAutoFilter = true;
        public bool IsAutoFilter {
            get { return _isAutoFilter; }
            set { _isAutoFilter = value; }
        }

        private readonly List<object> _fullList;
        private string _filterText { get; set; }
        public ComboBoxFinder() {
            IsTextSearchEnabled = false; // отключение автовыбора первого элемента, иначе не работает поиск
            _fullList = new List<object>();
            _filterText = "";

            KeyUp += (sender, args) => Filter(Text);
            KeyDown += (sender, args) => {
                if (_isAutoFilter) IsDropDownOpen = true;
                Filter(Text);
            };
            SelectionChanged += (sender, args) => {
                //if(SelectedItem != null)
                    Filter("");
            };
        }

        public void Filter(string text) {
            if (!_isAutoFilter) return;
            if (text.IsNull()) return;

            _filterText = text;
            if (_fullList.Count < 1)
                foreach (var isc in Items.SourceCollection)
                    _fullList.Add(isc);

            var tmpSourceList = _fullList.Where(fl => fl != null && fl.ToString().ToUpper().Contains(_filterText.ToUpper())).ToList();
            //if (tmpSourceList.Count == 1) return;
            ItemsSource = tmpSourceList;
        }
    }
}
```

Вроде как выполняется то что нужно, но работает как-то криво.
Когда выбираешь первый раз элемент отображается в заголовка, начинаю печатать для второго поиска, первая буква печатается и потом исчезает, нужно вводить ее снова, после чего все фильтруется нормально. Или второй вариант при попытке напечатать текст выскакивает выбранный элемент и данные не фильтруются.

Какая ошибка когда появляется пока не пойму. Подскажите куда смотреть. WinForms использовать нельзя, т.к. не вписывается в проект. В интернете ничего не нарыл, такое ощущение что все под WinForms пишут (

Comment: Видимо кроме меня с этим никто не сталкивался
Оставлю пока так, пущай работает пока нужная мысля не придет

Comment: Вы почему-то пытаетесь работать на уровне View. Это не выглядит очень правильно. В любом случае у вас всё как-то сложно, почему не через ItemsSource/Filter?

Answer (score 7):

У меня работает так:

XAML:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" x:Name="CB"
          TextBoxBase.TextChanged="OnComboboxTextChanged"
          IsTextSearchEnabled="False" IsEditable="True"
          VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

Code-behind:

```
void OnComboboxTextChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CB.IsDropDownOpen = true;
    // убрать selection, если dropdown только открылся
    var tb = (TextBox)e.OriginalSource;
    tb.Select(tb.SelectionStart + tb.SelectionLength, 0);
    CollectionView cv = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(CB.ItemsSource);
    cv.Filter = s =>
        ((string)s).IndexOf(CB.Text, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0;
}
```

Результат:

[image: Анимашка. Все любят анимашки.]

Answer (score 0):

Улучшил поиск

XAML:

```
<ComboBox Name="CB"
          Height="26"
          IsTextSearchEnabled="False"
          IsEditable="True"
          TextBoxBase.TextChanged="ComboBox_TextChanged"
          ItemsSource="{Binding SearchList}">
</ComboBox>
```

Код View:

```
    private void ComboBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var tb = (TextBox)e.OriginalSource;
        if (tb.SelectionStart != 0)
        {
            CB.SelectedItem = null; // Если набирается текст сбросить выбраный элемент
        }
        if (tb.SelectionStart == 0 && CB.SelectedItem == null)
        {
            CB.IsDropDownOpen = false; // Если сбросили текст и элемент не выбран, сбросить фокус выпадающего списка
        }

        CB.IsDropDownOpen = true;
        if (CB.SelectedItem == null)
        {
            // Если элемент не выбран менять фильтр
            CollectionView cv = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(CB.ItemsSource);
            cv.Filter = s => ((string)s).IndexOf(CB.Text, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0;
        }
    }
```