# Как убрать у ComboBox'a на DropDown автоматическое выделение текста?

Tags: wpf

ComboBox `IsEditable`. Повесил обработчик на изменение текста. Обработчик пробегает по таблице, делает `List` и отдаёт в `ItemSource`, затем открывает `DropDownOpen` ComboBox'a. На `DropDown`'e, если `Text` ComboBox'a не соответствует какому-нибудь `Item` у `ItemSource`, ComboBox выделяет весь текст. Если продолжить набирать, то тест стирается и нужно печатать заново.

```
private async void ComboBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    SearchComboBox(sender as ComboBox);
}

private void SearchComboBox(ComboBox control)
{
    if (control.IsKeyboardFocusWithin)
        if (control.Name == "LocationComboBox")
        {
            control.ItemsSource = MainDB.Locations.Where(loc => loc.Name.ToLower().Contains(LocationComboBox.Text.ToLower())).ToList();
            control.IsDropDownOpen = true;
        }
}
```

Пример:

[image: Пример]

п.с. Если есть ссылка на подробный туториал как сделать свой комбобокс с нуля, прошу поделится.

Comment: AutoTextSelection такое свойство разве есть? Что-то я его не нахожу [ссылка](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox_properties(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Нет, прошу прощения, что ввел в заблуждение. Имел ввиду автоматическое выделение текста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/576463/10105) сработало такое:

```
void ComboBox_TextChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var cb = (Combobox)sender;

    if (cb.IsKeyboardFocusWithin && cb.Name == "LocationComboBox")
    {
        cb.ItemsSource = MainDB.Locations.Where(loc => 
            loc.Name.IndexOf(LocationComboBox.Text,
                             StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).ToList();
        cb.IsDropDownOpen = true;
        // убрать selection, если dropdown только открылся
        var tb = (TextBox)e.OriginalSource;
        tb.Select(tb.SelectionStart + tb.SelectionLength, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`IsTextSearchEnabled="False"` тогда не будет искать среди элементов (вы же сами ищете с помощью своего метода) и выделять, и отображать недостающие буквы.

Comment: control.IsDropDownOpen = true; по прежнему выделяет тест

Answer (score 0):

При закрытии dropdownbox DBLookupComboboxEh (компоненты EhLib) происходит выделение текста.
Убрать выделение возможно в событии OnClose:
DBLookupComboboxEh->Deselect();