# Перенесение фокуса с `TextBox` на соседний `TextBox` по нажатию кнопки "стрелка вниз"

Tags: c#, wpf

Реализую поиск по вводимым символам из БД: когда пользователь вводит букву, то из БД извлекаются слова начинающиеся с этой же буквы. Поиск работает, список слов появляется, но вот не работает перенос фокуса по нажатию стрелки вниз с поля ввода на варианты выбора. Иллюстрация и пример кода ниже.

[image: иллюстрация работы]

XAML

```
         <StackPanel Margin="0,5,0,0">
                <TextBox x:Name="textBoxSearch" KeyUp="textBoxSearch_KeyUp"
                         Width="250" Height="23" />
                <Border x:Name="borderHint" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black"
                        Width="250" Height="95" Margin="0,2,0,0" Visibility="Collapsed" >
                    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                        <StackPanel x:Name="stackHint"></StackPanel>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </StackPanel>
```

Начало метода где пытаюсь перенести фокус

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Ввод текста в поле для поиска слова
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private async void textBoxSearch_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        //если нажата стрелка вниз
        if (e.Key == Key.Down && borderHint.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
        {
            //TODO: сделать перенос фокуса на первое слово в списке
            if (stackHint.Children.Count > 0)
            {
                scrollViewer.Focus();
                //stackHint.Focus();
                //stackHint.Children[0].Focus();
                //var b = stackHint.Children[0].Focusable;
            }
            return;
        }

        //ссылка на вводимый текст
        string query = (sender as TextBox).Text;

        //очищаем бордер от предыдущих элементов
        this.stackHint.Children.Clear();

        //управление видимостью бордера
        if (query.Length == 0)
        {
            //если ничего не введено, прячем бордер  
            this.borderHint.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            //если что-то введено, то показываем бордер  
            this.borderHint.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        }

        //запрашиваем подходящие слова
        List<string> hints = await ((ListWordsViewModel)this.DataContext).GetHints(query);
        //показываем в зависимости от результата
        if (hints.Any())
        {
            AddHints(hints);
        }
        else
        {
            this.stackHint.Children.Add(new TextBlock() { Text = "Ничего не найдено." });
        }
    }

    private void AddHints(List<string> hints)
    {
        TextBlock block = null;
        foreach (var hint in hints)
        {
            //добавляем содержимое подсказки 
            block = new TextBlock();
            block.Text = hint;
            //стиль  
            block.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;

            //События мыши
            block.MouseLeftButtonUp += (sender, e) =>
            {
                //вводим выбранную подсказку
                this.textBoxSearch.Text = (sender as TextBlock).Text;
                //прячем остальные подсказки
                this.borderHint.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                //передаем нужный текст во ViewModel
                ((ListWordsViewModel)this.DataContext).SearchText = this.textBoxSearch.Text;
            };

            block.MouseEnter += (sender, e) =>
            {
                TextBlock b = sender as TextBlock;
                b.Background = Brushes.LightBlue;
            };

            block.MouseLeave += (sender, e) =>
            {
                TextBlock b = sender as TextBlock;
                b.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
            };

            //отображение подсказки   
            this.stackHint.Children.Add(block);
        }
    }
```

Далее в этом методе идет извлечение подходящих слов из БД и наполнение `this.stackHint` `TextBlock`ами с нужными словами. Так вот хочется переносить фокус на первый `TextBlock` чтоб стрелкой можно было выбирать из списка. Я пошагово проходил, условие отрабатывает, но фокус в интерфейсе почему-то не меняется.
 Что посоветуете?

P.S.

```
            if (stackHint.Children.Count > 0)
            {
                scrollViewer.Focus();

                var b = stackHint.Children[0].Focusable;

            }
```

Фокус на `scrollViewer` переходит, но дальше листать стрелкой все равно невозможно.
А вот `b == false`

Comment: А вот это не оно: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/576463/10105?

Comment: Ну и если у вас `stackHint.Children[0].Focusable == false`, то покажите, как вы добавляете элементы в `stackHint`.

Comment: @VladD по ссылке играются с ComboBox, у меня все иначе

Comment: @VladD добавил полную версию как чего.

Comment: Ну да, но я имел в виду, может быть имеет смысл не делать вручную, а перелезть на комбобокс?

Comment: @VladD, ладно, я пока другим займусь, если ответы не придут, то тогда задумаюсь о ComboBox, может быть...

Comment: StackPanel, который вы используете как контейнер, поддерживает только самую простую компоновку элементов и вряд ли поддерживает навигацию. Попробуйте заменить его на ListBox например.

Comment: @AntonPapin оформите, пожалуйста, ваш совет в качестве ответа, и я его отплюсую...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StackPanel`, который вы используете как контейнер, поддерживает только самую простую компоновку элементов и не поддерживает навигацию. Попробуйте заменить его на более продвинутый контейнер, например `ListBox`.

Comment: Спасибо, с ListBox заработало.

Answer (score 1):

У меня вполне сработало перенесение фокуса в вашем коде, когда я заменил

```
block = new TextBlock();
```

на

```
block = new TextBlock() { Focusable = true };
```

а также закомментировал

```
scrollViewer.Focus();
```

и раскомментировал

```
stackHint.Children[0].Focus();
```

---

Отладка UI с фокусом в пошаговом режиме — не лучшая идея. Дело в том, что при переключении в отладчик приложение теряет фокус, и соответственно ведёт себя не самым удобным образом. Увы. Приходится использовать логирование.

Comment: Спасибо, я сейчас проверю... Я пока по совету Anton Papin сметил стекпэнел на листбокс и все заработало, час попробую сделать как вы советуете.

Comment: @Bulson: Угу, у листбокса тоже `ListBoxItem`'ы имеют атрибут `Focusable == true`.

Comment: Фокус как бы появляется, да. Но, после выбора и нажатия на Enter не происходит выбора нужного элемента.

Comment: @Bulson: Ну да, а с чего он должен? У вас же панели от нажатия Enter не исчезают сами по себе? У `Combobox` это прописано в его логике, а у вас где?

Comment: Да, я забыл, что надо подписаться на событие нажатия, да. И с ListBox мне вариант понравился, что он сразу выделяет цветом элемент в фокусе, а не как панель просто пунктиром. Спасибо, я дальше уже сам разберусь...

Comment: @Bulson: Ну вот и отлично. Да, фокус и всё такое хорошо бы тоже получить автоматически, а не писать вручную. `ListBox` несомненно лучше, чем `StackPanel`. Но всё же попробуйте и комбобокс :)

Comment: Вы извините, но я все же  Anton Papin засчитал ответ, у него и оценок совсем немного, а вам я думаю, не очень обидно будет, правда :)

Comment: @Bulson: Не вопрос, я ещё наберу :-P