# Убрать Смещение StackPanel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
До начала ввода текста

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После ввода текст бокс

```
<StackPanel Name="equalsWord"  Width="350" Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBox Name="Search" TextChanged="Search_TextChanged" Background="#EEE"
                 Width="90" 
                 Height="20" 
                 FontSize="30" 
                 FontWeight="Light" 
                 TextAlignment="Center"
                 BorderBrush="#F3E9F1"
                 BorderThickness="3" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" MaxLength="10"/>
            <StackPanel Name="ToList" ></StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
```

Код C#
происходит при вводе текста в поле.

```
private void Search_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ToList.Children.Clear();

            List<string> NewWord = Word.Where(g => g.Contains(Search.Text)).ToList();
            foreach (var item in NewWord)
            {
                label = new Label();
                label.Height = 40;
                label.BorderBrush = Brushes.Gray;
                label.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 0, 1, 0);
                label.FontSize = 20;
                label.MouseEnter += listMouseEnter;
                label.MouseLeave += listMouseLeave;
                label.Background = Brushes.White;
                label.VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
                label.HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                label.Content = item;
                ToList.Children.Add(label);
            }
        }
```

Метод выборки из таблицы

```
void SelectDate()
        {
            try
            {
                using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    command = new SqlCommand("select Name from ListOperators", connection);
                    reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        Word.Add(reader["Name"].ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (connection != null)
                    connection.Close();
            }
        }
```

Так вот собственно проблема в том что StackPanel смещается в верх как бы 
расширяясь в высоту в обе стороны  а я хочу что бы она увеличивалась тока в низ то есть добавлялись Label тока в низ под TextBox.

Comment: надо бы добавить картинку, как выглядит это все, иначе визуально трудно представить.

Comment: кинул  картинки .

Comment: Вместо `StackPanel` чтобы удовлетворять "... я хочу что бы она увеличивалась тока в низ... " попробуйте использовать `ListBox`

Comment: в `ListBox` нельзя дочерни элементы добавить .UPDATE      добавил элементы через `ToList.Items.Add(label);` но пробьлемы это не решело

Comment: А не нужно дочерний, нужно коллекцию наполнять, которая привязана к `ListBox`. Кстати, я сам нечто похожее реализовывал и у меня возникла примерно такая же проблема, а может и не похожая, но примерно в этом ключе, [посмотрите](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/619411/222542) может поможет.

Comment: Почему не использовать `ComboBox`?

Comment: `sp7` не знаю.Решил так сделать вот и пытаюсь реализовать

Comment: Вы хотите сделать LifeSearch по примеру того, как это реализовано в  `Google`, `Yandex`?

Comment: ну да типа поиска. Вводиш букву или слово он ищет все где это есть.Сам поиск нормально работает проблема со смещением чем больше элементов находит тем сильнее вверх сещается

Comment: Вы пытаетесь вручную сделать комбобокс. Не изобретайте велосипед, делайте сразу правильно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<StackPanel Name="equalsWord"  Width="350" Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="84,142,83,0">
```

Если не нравится `Margin="84,142,83,0"` то замени на grid в % центра экрана

Comment: игрался также с маржин но выравние вертикальное по центру оставлял не помгало думал так не прокатит  а оказывается работате если выравнивание сменить.Спасибо