# Как переместить курсор в конец редактируемого текста в ComboBox WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

Программно меняю текст (.Text) в редактируемом (IsEditable=true) ComboBox в WPF. Курсор при этом ставится в начало текста, и если пользователь сразу же продолжает ввод, то строка портится. Как после программной ставки текста переместить курсор в конец строки?

Попытки загуглить решение ответа не дали.
Для WinForm советуют:

```
comboBox1.SelectionStart = comboBox1.Text.Lenght - 1

comboBox1.Select(comboBox1.Text.Length, 0);
```

Но у меня WPF, и у его контрола ComboBox нет свойства SelectionStart и метода Select

Comment: Добраться до TextBox в шаблоне элемента и вызвать нужные методы у него

Comment: Вот это не подойдёт? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/576463/10105

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Необходимо извлечь TextBox, который лежит внутри шаблона ComboBox. Проще всего это сделать по имени. В коде cbExample - это имя ComboBox в котором надо управлять курсором. Ну и если у вас установка курсора идет на какое-то действие в другом визуальном элементе, то надо передать в TextBox фокус:

```
var textBox = (TextBox)cbExample.Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", cbExample);
textBox.Text = "asgasgasdgf";
textBox.Focus();
textBox.SelectionStart = textBox.Text.Length;
```

Если вы будете стилем или еще как-то переопределять шаблон для ComboBox, то предложенный код может не работать.

Comment: @Андрей-Кутасевич , Вы решили свою проблему?