# В чем проблема с combobox в c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, поиск, combobox

я новичок, но хочу разобрать с поиском в выпадающем списке ComboBox. Нашел код на просторах сайта, списал его, но здесь выдается ошибка.

```
public Agent prodSale { get; set; } = new Agent();
TextBox poiskname = new TextBox();
public HisAdd()
{
    InitializeComponent();
       
    CB.ItemsSource = Entities1.GetContext().Product.ToList();
}
void OnComboboxTextChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var tb=(TextBox)e.OriginalSource;
    if (tb.SelectionStart != 0)
    {
        CB.SelectedItem = null;
    }
    if(tb.SelectionStart == 0 && CB.SelectedItem == null)
    {
        CB.IsDropDownOpen = false;
    }
    CB.IsDropDownOpen = true;
       
    if (CB.SelectedItem == null)
    {
        CollectionView cv = 
 (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(CB.ItemsSource);
        cv.Filter = s => ((string)s).IndexOf(tb.Text, 
StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0;
    }
}
```

[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/549935/Живой-поиск-system-windows-controls-combobox-c-wpf/1379611?noredirect=1#comment2451547_1379611](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/549935/%D0%96%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-system-windows-controls-combobox-c-wpf/1379611?noredirect=1#comment2451547_1379611)

[image: скрин xaml]
[image: скрин кода и ошибки]

Comment: Это что? WPF? Приложите код текстом.

Comment: wpf, добавила текст

Comment: `cv.Filter = s => s?.ToString().Contains(tb.Text, 
StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) ?? false;` вроде `cv.Refresh();` еще надо вызвать после присвоения фильтра.

Comment: ошибка красным подсвечивается в Contains пишет(Ни одна из перегрузок метода "contains" не принимает 2 аргументов)

Comment: `StringComparison` на `StringComparer` поменяйте, версия .NET какая?

Comment: .NET Framework 4.7.2, исправила на StringComparer, но все равно ошибка в contains

Comment: А, это очень старый .NET, я не помню как там было, можно попробовать так накостылить `s?.ToString().ToLower().Contains(tb.Text.ToLower().Trim()) ?? false;`

Comment: сделала, как вы сказали. Теперь программа запускается, но поиск все равно не работает: имеем: газета большая, газета спам. Вводим "газета" комбобокс.итемов становится меньше, но они белые(прозрачные):(((((

Comment: Refresh вызываете?

Comment: Да, вызываю в конце